# c# DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern doesn't corresponds to "d" predefined format

Tags: c#

I have a problem stringifying dates in various cultures. Some time ago I posted a question on SO about it ([C# DateTime ToString Standard culture format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515391/c-sharp-datetime-tostring-standard-culture-format)) and I implemented the solution posted there. But it's not working on Portuguese (for example) because ShortDatePattern is not equals than "d" predefined format:

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetSpecificCulture("pt-PT");
DateTime date = new DateTime(2019, 7, 26);
date.ToString("d", ci); // --> 26-07-2019
date.ToString(ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, ci); // --> 26/07/2019
```

How can I get the real format of a predefined style. I've seen the .Net source code of datetime.cs, and I can't understand how it works because following code "d" uses "ShortDatePattern" (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeformat.cs,f4cacf1a27a6de16).

And I think that it depends on the machine that runs the code, because in some environments the "d" and ShortDatePattern is the same...

Comment: Both lines return the same string

Comment: I get `26/07/2019` on both lines as well, but I'm running from Xamarin Studio on macOS. Maybe `System.Globalization` has different CultureInfo data on different platforms?

Comment: Are you sure about that "GetSpecificCulture"? I had to use either `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-PT")` or `new CultureInfo("pt-PT")` (on LinqPad) (and both returned two "26/07/2019" values)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I've found the response, I must use CreateSpecificCulture as you points... on my computer, it uses dashes as separator, but returns the same (using CreateSpecificCulture).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've found my problem, in my real code I was using GetCultureInfo, however when I write the code on the question (by heart) I've used CreateSpecificCulture. So, I've modified the question to match with the real code and now I write the answer to leave here if anyone has a similar problem.

To solve the problem above I must use CreateSpecificCulture:

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-PT");
DateTime date = new DateTime(2019, 7, 26);
date.ToString("d", ci); // --> 26-07-2019
date.ToString(ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, ci); // --> 26-07-2019
```

More info about differences between CreateSpecificCulture and GetCultureInfo: [When to use CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(String) or CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(String)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986754/when-to-use-cultureinfo-getcultureinfostring-or-cultureinfo-createspecificcult)